# Datatables plugin columns fix don’t start programatically

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is the situation; I have three html tables created programmatically in my php page. In document ready try to start the plugin .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.genetictable').each(function(){

       var tabla = $(this).DataTable( {
          scrollY:        500,
          scrollX: true
       } );
    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( tabla , {
    leftColumns: 3
 } );
});
```

The plugin starts well, but the fixedColumn functionality don’t start until I manually click in column for order it.

After

```
 new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns( tabla , {
    leftColumns: 3
 } );
```

I try:
Order programmatically :

```
tabla.column(3).data().sort();
```

draw() functionality :

```
tabla.draw( 'page' );
tabla.draw( false );
```

Try draw() and order functionality:

```
table.order( [[ 3, 'desc' ]] ).draw( false );
```

**None works**
The functionality also start if push f12 or inspect element in Mozilla.

Any change to achive this for my multiple tables?

Comment: @user242794 did you try using the fixed colum property in declaration? :
`  fixedColumns:   {
            leftColumns: 1,
            rightColumns: 1
        }`

Comment: yes , the behavior is the same

Answer (score 0):

Finally the problem was caused by a boostrap tab , the asnwwer is here https://github.com/DataTables/Responsive/issues/40. Hope save time to others.